# Cache-Control in node.js http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making requests to JSON objects with node using http.get(), it all works fine but, in some cases, I get an outdated version of the page (there's a date field that enables me to make sure). The behaviour is really inconsistent, I can get the right thing one moment, and the wrong thing the next... Here's my request :

```
var options = {host:'host.com',path:urlPath,headers:{'Cache-Control':'no-cache'}}
http.get(options, function(res){
    //JSON.parse result and check the date, sometimes 17/1, sometimes 10/1
});
```

Is there anything wrong with the request header? I tried 'max-age=0' instead of 'no-cache', to no avail..., does anyone have an idea where this could come from? In my browser, I get the last version all the time, a bit lost here, Help!

Comment: Have you tried appending a random string at the end? E.g. `'host.com'+(new Date().valueOf())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it, thanks to users comment, what I did is :

```
urlPath+="&ie="+(new Date()).getTime();
var options = {host:'host.com',path:urlPath,headers:{'Cache-Control':'no-cache'}}
http.get(options, function(res){
    //JSON.parse result and check the date, sometimes 17/1, sometimes 10/1
});
```

Stupid and awesome at the same time...